# Is it really impossible to make a div fit its size to its content?

Tags: html, size, width

I'd like to clarify whether it's possible or not to make a div fit its size based on the content's size without having to make elements float or having to make their position absolute. Is it possible?

Comment: Imagine how much simpler web dev would have been if we could do this! **I want `display: block-inline`!!** (that is to behave outwardly as a block but inwardly as an inline - the opposite of `inline-block`)

Answer (score 158, accepted):

### CSS `display` setting

It is of course [possible - JSFiddle proof of concept](http://jsfiddle.net/XgErJ/4) where you
can see all three possible solutions:

- `display: inline-block` - **this is the one you're not aware of**
- `position: absolute`
- `float: left/right`

Comment: Thank you! I hadn't considered inline-block!

Comment: Brilliant answer, thank you!  My case: Use `display: inline-block;` *and* check/remove any other styles with `width` or `height` attributes affecting said attributes.

Answer (score 26):

You can use [`display: inline-block`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/display#Values).

Comment: I've updated my proof of concept JSFiddle that also shows the possibility with `position:absolute`. It is as well possible. Click the link in my answer.

Answer (score 16):

You can use:

```css
width: -webkit-fit-content;
height: -webkit-fit-content;
width: -moz-fit-content;
height: -moz-fit-content;
```

**EDIT:** No. see http://red-team-design.com/horizontal-centering-using-css-fit-content-value/

**ALSO:**
http://dev.w3.org/csswg/css-box-3/

Comment: Is this a troll answer? fit-content is not a valid property value for width or height.

Comment: It works but you must set the value to `-webkit-fit-content` or `-moz-fit-content` depending on browser you use.

Comment: As of 2021, Desktop browsers do support this without the webkit or moz prefixes, though apparently mobile broswers still require the prefixes. See https://caniuse.com/?search=fit-content

Answer (score 5):

it works well on Edge and Chrome:

```
  width: fit-content;
  height: fit-content;
```

Answer (score 4):

you can also use

> word-break: break-all;

when nothing seems working this works always ;)