# How to fit the height of a div to its contents? Other answers did not resolve it

Tags: html, css

I want to create a header bar at the top of the web-page, give it a background color and then add a logo on it.

So the problem is:

- The width of the bar should be the *width of the page*. **Its height
  should be the size of the logo (plus some padding added around the
  logo image).**

  **Or is there a way to make the bar as big as its
  content plus the padding added to the content?**

---

I actually searched [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5903112/is-it-really-impossible-to-make-a-div-fit-its-size-to-its-content) and [found this](http://jsfiddle.net/XgErJ/4/), I tried to reproduce it into my code but it does not seem to help me.

I have also seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20267675/div-height-doesnt-adjust-to-fit-content) and [this](http://jsfiddle.net/logintomyk/Xxfhn/).

My code is as follows:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

    <head>
        <title>TODO supply a title</title>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <style>
            .div {
                position: absolute;
                height: auto; //**** When changed to a percent value, it displays
                width: 100%;
                top: 0px;
                left: 0px;
                float: left;
                background: #000029;
            }
            .logo {
                position: fixed;
                top: 5px;
                left: 12px;
                bottom: 4px;
            }
        </style>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div class="div">

             <img src="http://********Header.svg" alt="Logo" class="logo" >

        </div>
    </body>

</html>
```

It just does not display the background color at all, and when I change the value of height to some value in percent, it displays.

**So what I want is that the height of the bar should fit to its content i.e. the logo image.**

---

EDIT:-

[image]

Comment: Why are you positioning the div absolutely? Absolute positioning and floating don't mix. Also, fixed positioning is relative to the viewport. And I hope you're not using that comment syntax in your actual page anywhere. Finally, why wouldn't you share the link to the actual image? You're asking for help so that makes no sense.

Comment: Is there a reason for using position absolute and fixed attributes?

Comment: you have to remove `position: fixed;` for `logo` or change to `relative`

Comment: @Anurag For absolute positioning, yes! I saw the CSS for the div with id `abs` from [here](http://jsfiddle.net/XgErJ/4/)

Comment: Whoever is down-voting, please bother telling me the reason as well, otherwise your down-votes do no good!

Comment: @j08691 Because for this I was just using a logo from the internet for practice, I do not have an original logo yet. I think I am not authorized to use that logo, so I commented it. Yes I asked for help but it was not related to the logo I used. Hope I redeemed myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change you css code like below:

```
.div {
      position: fixed;  
      width: 100%;
      top: 0px;
      left: 0px;
      background: #000029;
      padding:5px;
      }

       .logo {               
        }
```

see the demo here ---->http://jsfiddle.net/4A7Q9/1/

Answer (score 3):

Remove virtually all of your CSS rules and just use something as basic as:

```
.div {
    background: #000029;
}
.logo {
    vertical-align:top;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/7HVSL/)**

Comment: you forgot width:100% for the .div

Comment: @Anurag - Divs are 100% width by default. They're block elements.

Comment: I still don't trust IE enough to leave them as default. I feel safer writing it. :)

Comment: No it does not produce the desired result. It produces a padding kinda thing around the div. I am posting a screenshot.

Answer (score 1):

The style can be something along these lines:

```
<style>
            .div {

                width: 100%;
                background: #000029;
                padding-left:10px;
                padding-right:10px;
                padding-top:10px;
                padding-bottom:10px;
            }
            .logo {

            }
        </style>
```