# Fit to content for Bootstrap alert

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a Bootstrap alert and I want the width to fit the content. In the Bootstrap documentation it appears the default is to have 100% width. What is the most robust way to make the alert exactly fit its content on all screen sizes?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="alert alert-danger">
        My short alert message.
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Off hand, I don't know of "some CSS" that will fit it to the content. Additionally, maybe there is a built in Bootstrap class that can do it? I couldn't find one by searching through the documentation.

Comment: Start playing around with your browser's inspector and try some stuff. I'd suggest starting with floats, or turning it into an inline-block element. SO isn't really a "write me code because I don't want to experiment" place.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You just need to add `display: inline-block`

#### Demo in Stack Snippets:

```css
.alert-trim {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.css">

<div class="container">
  <div class="alert alert-danger">
    Normal Alert Message
  </div>

  <div class="alert alert-danger alert-trim">
    Trimmed Alert Message
  </div>
</div>
```

**See Also**: [Is it really impossible to make a div fit its size to its content?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5903112/1366033)

Comment: If only all answers were this simple and straight to the point! 
Thank you.

Comment: glad it helped! :)

Comment: ow do you limit the `container` so that it stretches to fit content but not more?